# Why do I get SignatureVerificationException when trying to validate a JWT with PS256?

Tags: java, jwt

I'm trying to verify a signature on a JWT. This is (part of) my code:

```
DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
...
JwkProvider provider = new JwkProviderBuilder(jwksUrl).build();
Jwk jwk = provider.get(jwt.getKeyId());         
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);
algorithm.verify(jwt);
```

and I just get this error:

```
com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.SignatureVerificationException: The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: SHA256withRSA
```

However I can see in the jwt the algorithm shows as PS256 rather than RSA256. Is this the problem? How can I get this to verify the JWT? There isn't an enum option for PS256 on Algorithm.  saw somewhere that it might be RSASSA-PS but I don't see an option for that either

More info: The JWT is passed to me in an odd way by an external provider, it isn't just a bearer token in an HTTP header so I need to do this myself rather than relying on a framework to handle it.
I'm using Java 17.
Relevant dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
          <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
          <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>
          <version>0.21.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked out the answer using [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jwt-token-decode) but I did have to add some value of my own. Here's the solution:

```
DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
URL url = new
JwkProvider provider = new JwkProviderBuilder(jwksUrl)
  .build();
 Jwk jwk = provider.get(jwt.getKeyId());
SignatureAlgorithm sa = SignatureAlgorithm
  .forName(jwt.getAlgorithm());
DefaultJwtSignatureValidator validator = 
  new DefaultJwtSignatureValidator(sa, jwk.getPublicKey());
if (!validator.isValid(jwt.getHeader()+"."+jwt.getPayload(), jwt.getSignature())) {
    throw new Exception("Could not verify JWT token integrity!");
}
```

To make this work I had to add jjwt to my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
  <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The `.forName()` call means that it handles different algorithms, depending on what `alg` is specified in the JWT.